# Constant interrutions in very slow Wifi brcmfmac43241b4-sdio in VAIO pro 13

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom, vaio

my wifi works but is very slow and I have constant interruptions.
I get in /var/log/syslog

```
kernel: [ 2125.408367] brcmfmac: brcmf_escan_timeout: timer expired
```

nm-tool:
    nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [HNET] --------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            brcmfmac_sdio
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        XXXXXXXXXXX  (hidden)

  Capabilities:
  Speed:           11 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
  WEP Encryption:  yes
  WPA Encryption:  yes
  WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
  *HNET:           Infra,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39
  ZWGLBDATA:       Infra, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 WPA WPA2 Enterprise

  IPv4 Settings:
  Address:         10.1.82.179
  Prefix:          19 (255.255.224.0)
  Gateway:         10.1.64.1

  DNS:             10.1.64.1

can somebody help?

Comment: Odd. I also got a Vaio Pro 13, and although I also have issues with my Wifi, my computer uses iwlwifi. Could you post a lspsci?

Comment: You're relatively lucky, I've got one which won't even connect to a successfully scanned network; the search hints that nvram file is quite platform-specific (and this is the reason it's not generally shipped), try looking for other `brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.txt` variants but do back up what you already have (probably as `/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.txt`).
Might be useful either: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Edit your iwlwifi.conf

```
nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Comment the last three lines and add this:

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 power_save=1
```

Your file should end like this:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
#remove iwlwifi \
#(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
#&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 power_save=1
```

Reboot